# Добавить новые xml элементы в файл, выбранный с помощью OpenDialog

Tags: c#, xml

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();

        using (sd)
        {
            if (sd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); 
                XmlElement root = document.CreateElement("mainroot");
                document.AppendChild(root);

                XmlElement name = document.CreateElement("Name");
                name.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
                document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(name);

                root.AppendChild(name);
                document.Save(sd.FileName);
```

Comment: Ну дык не создавайте новый, а открывайте указанный. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: В чем проблема? Вы до сих пор не решили?

Comment: @АндрейNOP решил, просто по другому сделал

Comment: Оформите решение ответом